Auto-calibrated speedometer for an Android Head unit notification bar
I'd like a better way of knowing my speed while driving, so I'm looking for an app which always shows my actual speed in the notification bar of my Android head unit, using GPS to correct the speed indicated by the speedometer..
Background
At the moment, I can see my GPS speed in Google maps, and of course I can see my speedometer measurement on my car dashboard, as well as in Torque, but neither tell me the true instantaneous speed of my vehicle.
The speedometer reacts instantaneously, but long term it's accuracy drifts with tyre wear, while GPS is highly accurate at a constant velocity, but takes a few moments to settle on a new speed when you brake or accelerate, so it's short term accuracy is can't be relied on.
This means that at the moment, when I'm driving, I approximate my true speed, in my head, using a combination of my car speedometer, and my speed according to my GPS. If my GPS says says 70mph, when I'm going a steady speed in a straight line, but my speedo indicates 75mph, then I know that at 30mph it will indicate around 32mph.
What I would like, is an app which will do this calculation for me. Monitor GPS vs speedometer speed and calculate and update a correction ratio whenever the speed is constant, and apply that correction to the speedometer.
This is a basic sensor fusion problem, solved decades ago with kalman filters, but there are hundreds of matches for "GPS speed notification" on the Play Store, and none of the one's I've looked at so far appear to put the speed in the notification bar, let alone do the speed correction that I seek.
Summary of desires

Android app
Current speed shown in the notification bar
Current speed updates quickly from the car speedometer
Speed calibrated using GPS data

